# Problem with scrolling when using Wowjs JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, wow.js

I used Wow.js plugin for animations when scrolling but i had a problem that occurs on mobile phones, when you reach Pricings section you'll be unable to scroll for some reason..
I'm using bootstrap 3 by the way

I've tried to change the animation effect but still makes no sense, so i guess it's not from the animation, after many tries i discovered that wowjs has nothing to do with this problem because i disabled it to try if it will work fine or not but still it doesn't work.

```html
<div class='plan col-md-4 wow bounceInUp'>
                    <div>
                        <div class='head'>
                            Basic
                        </div>
                        <div class='price'>
                            <p><span>$</span>0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='offer'>
                            <p>Free for Life</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class='list-unstyled'>
                            <li>1 GB of Space</li>
                            <li>10 GB of Bandwidth</li>
                            <li>3 Websites</li>
                            <li>Basic Customization</li>
                            <li>WordPress Integration</li>
                            <li>Email Support</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It should scroll normally but i don't really know what's wrong
here's the part i'm talking about
https://codepen.io/MohamedSalah97/pen/vozyVB

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: here it's 
https://codepen.io/MohamedSalah97/pen/vozyVB

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is because of using Nicescroll plugin which has many bugs that may affect scrolling on mobile phones also may affect scrolling on PC